# Fixing merge conflicts?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have two remote branches, "grape" and "master". I'm currently on "grape".

Now I switch to "master":

```
git checkout master
```

Now I want to pull all changes from "grape" into "master" - is this the way to do it?:

```
git merge origin grape
```

It's my understanding that git will then pull all the current state of the remote branch "grape" into my local copy of "master". It will try to auto-merge for me. If there are conflicts, the files in conflict will have some conflict text actually injected into the file. I then have to go into those files, and delete the chunk I don't want (essentially telling git how to merge these files).

For each file in conflict, do I add and commit the changes again?:

```
git add problemfile1.txt
git commit -m "Fixed merge conflict."

git add problemfile2.txt
git commit -m "Fixed another merge conflict."

...
```

after I've fixed all the merge conflicts like above, do I just push to "master" again to finish up the process?:

```
git push origin master
```

or is there something else we need to do when we get into this conflict state?

Thank you

Comment: One question in this time where you have written this complete post you could google for an answer or search here on stackoverflow ;) http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: do commit once, after all conflicts resolved. And don't specify commit message, it is generated automatically for the merge commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`origin` refers to another repository on another server; normally, it refers to the github server that you pulled the repo from.  If you want to merge grape and the master branch, then you'd `git merge grape`, resolve any conflicts, and the you can push the update to the server.

You resolve the merge by looking and editing the files it says there's a conflict in to be the way you want them to end up, add them to the index, and commit.

Comment: Ok so instead of "git merge origin grape", I should do "git merge grape"? The "grape" branch does happen to be a remote branch too, that's why I was confused if I need "origin" in there or not.

Comment: @user291701 yes, if you need more [`man git-merge`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should *first solve all merge conflicts* in files manually and then, you can commit and push to master and it will work.

If you do it the way you told, your commit history will be full of garbage commits and if you work on any projet with friends, that can be really annoying.